# DXA 1.7 dependencies not in Maven Central / not needed

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

I am building a DXA 1.7 web application for SDL Web 8.5 (using CIL). It is failing because on our build environment we only have access to Maven Central. It is failing on three types of dependencies, all of which I have questions about:

1. External dependencies - EasyLicense - Since I am using CIL this should not be needed right? Is there a certain profile/setting that I can set so it does not include this dependency?

   - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/release/1.7/local-project-repo/com/vs/ezlicrun/easylicense/2.5/easylicense-2.5.pom
2. SDL dependencies - Why are these not in Maven Central like the others?

   - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/release/1.7/local-project-repo/com/tridion/cd_broker/8.5.0-1021/cd_broker-8.5.0-1021.pom
   - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/release/1.7/local-project-repo/com/sdl/web/discovery-client-lightweight/8.5.0-1022/discovery-client-lightweight-8.5.0-1022.pom
   - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/release/1.7/local-project-repo/com/tridion/cd_common_config/8.5.0-1016/cd_common_config-8.5.0-1016.pom
   - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/release/1.7/local-project-repo/com/tridion/cd_common_config_api/8.5.0-1016/cd_common_config_api-8.5.0-1016.pom
   - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/release/1.7/local-project-repo/com/sdl/web/content-linking/8.5.0-1028/content-linking-8.5.0-1028.pom
   - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/release/1.7/local-project-repo/com/sdl/web/content-dynamic/8.5.0-1028/content-dynamic-8.5.0-1028.pom
   - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/release/1.7/local-project-repo/com/sdl/web/web-ambient-engine/8.5.0-1015/web-ambient-engine-8.5.0-1015.pom
3. Custom DD4T 2.0 dependencies - What has been customized in DD4T and why?

   - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/release/1.7/local-project-repo/org/dd4t/dd4t-api/2.1.4-DXA17/dd4t-api-2.1.4-DXA17.pom
   - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/release/1.7/local-project-repo/org/dd4t/dd4t-core/2.1.4-DXA17/dd4t-core-2.1.4-DXA17.pom
   - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/release/1.7/local-project-repo/org/dd4t/dd4t-databind/2.1.4-DXA17/dd4t-databind-2.1.4-DXA17.pom
   - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/release/1.7/local-project-repo/org/dd4t/dd4t-providers/2.1.4-DXA17/dd4t-providers-2.1.4-DXA17.pom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For future reference: We had to put the artifacts from #3 in the local repository, after that the build worked. We did not need to exclude #1 and #2.
(I must post this as an anwser since I am not permitted to comment)

Comment: You don't have to apologize; this looks like a genuine Answer to me. :-)

Answer (score 6):

1. You don't need easylicense, that's right. There were some known (and
   fixed in some later versions) bugs in CIL when some artifacts were
   still dependent on CIS stuff. Simply exclude easylicense from the
   build then.
2. Same as with #1. I don't see them in DXA poms, and I am surprised that you have these problems. Apparently, they come through CIL dependency. The only nice way then to build the framework is to exclude those transitive dependencies.
3. Although this is not really nice, it's a mistake made when first migrated to SDL Web 8. This **is not DD4T 2**, this is DD4T 1.something. That time there was no support of Web 8 in DD4T, so this is a custom fork implementing really basic things to support it. Currently it's a legacy mistake that better should be re-worked

Comment: Thanks Alexey - I'm not yet a Maven ninja - how would you exclude these dependencies?

Comment: Something like this https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/blob/develop/dxa-oss-parent/pom.xml#L255

Comment: Regarding #3: IIRC, we used a fork from DD4T 2.0.2. So, it *is* DD4T 2.0.

Comment: Regarding #3 indeed it was a fork of DD4T 2 since DD4T 2 Java was still in beta and not officially released