# Dependencies missing in DXA 2.2 - Java

Tags: dxa, dxa-java, dxa2.2, sites-9.1

We are trying to upgrade DXA 2.0 to DXA 2.2 with SDL 9.1. We are including [DXA 2.2.5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sdl.dxa.modules/dxa-module-core/2.2.5.) as a dependency with no exclusions.

```
[WARNING] The POM for com.sdl.web:content-client-api:jar:8.5.0-1046 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.sdl.web:discovery-client-lightweight:jar:8.5.0-1036 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.sdl.web:content-linking:jar:8.5.0-1046 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.sdl.web:content-dynamic:jar:8.5.0-1046 is missing, no dependency information available
```

I checked the following repositories and the DXA 2.2.5 artifact references are missing from them which causes the WARNING in the first place. If there is a version that we should be refer from external maven repositories which probably have no Warnings.

Thanks in advance!

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sdl.web/content-client-api
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sdl.web/discovery-client-lightweight
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sdl.web/content-linking
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sdl.web/content-dynamic
```

How do I proceed to get a clean build apart from downloading the master branch and resolve all dependencies/exclusions manually? I did not see an answer to Dominic's question [here](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/21097/where-does-the-dependency-on-com-sdl-deliverycilpom11-0-0-0-1064-come-from).

Comment: I've updated the other question with an answer. The assets have now been correctly deployed to Maven Central by R&D. That was for 2.2.3. You may wish to check whether it also works for 2.2.5